# How to retrieve a particular image view from touch delegates?

Tags: ios, touch

I have a class in which i have one `UIScrollView` over self view.then i have a small `UIView` over that `ScrollView` and height of this small view is 200. I have 1 button and then through this I am selecting multiple images from elc picker and fill those images in array. Based on this array count I am adding number of `ImageView` over this small view. Now if i touch a `imageView` and move it in upward direction then I need to remove it.

Small view interaction is disabled. Rest all view and image view interactions are enabled.
when I touch any image view, I want to know which image view is selected, but through touch began method I am getting self view not image view.
I am using this statement.

```
UIImageView *imgV = (UIImageView *)touch.view;
```

Comment: setting Unique tag for each view so you can identifier eachview with it's tag

Comment: No.because if we move image view in upward direction then we have to remove imageview from super view and from array also.so tag will not work.

Comment: means?i am not getting..

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are explicitly setting `userInteractionEnabled` to `TRUE`on all your UIImageViews; by default it's set to `FALSE`, and thus will ignore all touch events.